# Globally changing a Java method

Tags: java, overriding

I have a bunch classes that extends another class, and want to change a function inside of it. Normally I'd you'd use an Override here, but since there are so many, I was wondering if there is a way to alter that method for every file in my project. I would simply copy the extended classes code and put it into a file I can alter myself, but I'm afraid I'd break something with how many classes it interacts with.

Comment: Alter a method everywhere is kind of the whole point for inheritance and overriding. Assuring there is no side effect is totaly dependant on your application

Comment: If you want to change a method in the parent class, why would you need to change the method in the children's class since they inherit the change?

Comment: Oh, I should have added that I don't have write access to the parent. Sorry.

Comment: you need to edit your question and show a [mcve]

Comment: You may be able to implement your own base class that extends the other base class.  In that class, override the method to provide the common behavior you want.